# Узнать количество элементов в классе, js

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть динамическая форма, с select'ом. Мне нужно узнать какие именно значения были выбраны. 
Вот таким образом делаю, но выбирает только активный первый элемент

```
var selection = $('.select_input').val();
```

А как вывести остальные? Пробую массивом

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < selection.length; ++i) {
        $('#'+selection).show();
}
```

Но выводит опять один элемент, скорее всего переменная только содержит 1 значение.

Изображение для понимания зачем. По id в селекте уже вывожу нужные поля.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такие параметры в select на всех формах.

```
id = types_val, class = form-control select_input
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
var vals = $(".select_input option:selected").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

В `vals` будут значения поля `value` выбранных `option` для каждого select'а.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А как теперь вывести? Вот таким образом `('#'+vals).show();` показывает в 2х полях, но одиноковое значение

Comment: `vals.forEach((val) => {
 alert(val);
});`